# Is there a way to see a user's reputation without the reputation cap?

Tags: support

I know that there is a limit to the reputation you can gain in one day (200). But is there a way to see an user's reputation without the reputation cap?

Like the sum of every upvote, downvote, edits and everything that gives and takes reputation?

Comment: It should be possible to whip something up with [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't know about https://data.stackexchange.com/ but now I figure it out and [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1047121/top-ten-users-if-there-was-no-reputation-cap) it is. Thanks for the comments and teaching me something new about SO.